# ArchLinux KDE sometimes mouseclick on the touchpad not working

Tags: linux, mouse, arch-linux, touchpad, kde

I'm running Arch Linux with KDE Plasma as desktop environment. Sometimes it happens that I suddenly can't use the double tap gesture on the touch-pad to make a mouse click also the two finger gestures to scroll in a window are not working. And the "Windows" key also stopped working (It  is configured to open the launcher menu (like the stat menu of windows)).

Does anyone have an idea where I can start searching for this problem?

Edit: Laptop is a Schenker XMG A504 and this is a barebone Clevo W355SS.

Comment: First off, try to run **as root** on a terminal the following cmd **"pacman -Syyuu"** for update all the system, so **"reboot"** the OS by cmd **reboot** and then if issue still occurs when the OS's up and running.

Comment: @jluizsouzadev I have this issue for about an year. It is not reproducible so easily. And I update my system regularly ;-)

Comment: Which are the laptop **model** and **manufacture**?

Comment: Schenker XMG A504. It is a barebone Clevo W355SS

Comment: [Arch Linux Touchpad Synaptics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Frequently_used_options)

Comment: Could you post here content of file **"/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf"** by run the cmd **"cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf"** on some terminal?

Comment: I don't have a 70-synaptics.conf there.I just now removed xf86-input-synaptics  because it is no longer actively updated. and I have libinput installed in paralell. So i removed xf86-input-synaptics .

Comment: Could you post here content of file **"/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf"** by run the cmd **"cat  /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf"** on some terminal?

Comment: [Arch Llinux libinput](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/libinput#Via_xinput)